# How do I set css so that the select button doesn't move when scrolled down?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

My script like this :

```
<v-col
    cols="12"
    md="12"
    style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; bottom: 0;background: white;"
>
    <v-btn class="success" block>Select</v-btn>
</v-col>
```

Demo and full code like this :
https://codepen.io/happyforever/pen/vYYoYNw?editors=1010

You can try it in mobile version and scroll down. When the scroll is in the lowest position, the select button moves up

I want the select button not to move when scrolling down

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **position: fixed**

```js
<v-col
    cols="12"
    md="12"
    style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;background: white;"
>
```

**EDIT**
*v-container* have padding by default. Set it to 0 on the bottom side. This will solve your problem.

Comment: if you use that, the width column becomes wider. Try it on codepen

Comment: It is because <v-container> have padding by default. Set it to 0 on the bottom side. On the third row in your code: <v-container style="padding-bottom: 0">

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot